# using variables in multiline define in gnumake

Tags: gnu-make

The Makefile:

```
define t1
a = $1
$(info  $(a) -- $(1))
endef

list = x y z

$(foreach  v,$(list),$(eval $(call t1,$(v))))
```

The output

```
 -- x
x -- y
y -- z
```

The problem is delaying of value of 'a' by one invocation. Even `a := $1` shows the same issue.

Any quick fixes ?

This is gnu make 3.81 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the confusing things about using `call` and `eval` together: when to add extra quoting.  The problem is that the `call` function is invoked first, and that will expand the argument once.  Then `eval` is called and that evaluates *its* argument (the output from `call`).

In your example, the `info` function is being evaluated by `call`, the first time, and so in that situation `a` has not been set yet (because it's not set until the `eval` function runs).  So you need to escape that function, and the expansion of `a`:

```
define t1
a = $1
$$(info $$(a) -- $(1))
endef
```

Comment: Got it. The problem of double evaluation .. Thanx.